# Why is SafeStrap disabled on my Motorola Droid 3 (Verizon)?

Tags: rooting, motorola-droid-x

I decided that I wanted to try out Ubuntu touch, but I don't want to put it on my current phone, so I decided to try to put it on my old Droid 3.

I followed these instructions to root the phone:

**[How To Install CyanogenMod Android for Motorola Droid 3](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_solana)**

All of the scripts were successful and I am able to run SafeStrap under root permissions. I installed the Recovery. BootStrap says that Safe System is not active.

When I reboot, the Safe Strap screen pops up. I press the menu button to start the recovery and I get a black screen. I noticed that when it starts up it says `SafeStrap: Disabled` in red.

How can I get SafeStrap to work?